# "Could not load NIB in bundle" when accessing .bundle content from framework embedded in pod

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, podspec

I have the following situation:

I need to integrate a third party framework into my own (local) cocoapod. The framework consist out of a .framework and a .bundle file. My .podspec file looks like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'flutter_wrapper'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'Flutter wrapper for the client framework Mobile SDK'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
  Wraps the [client Mobile SDK][1] for use in Flutter apps.
  [1]: https://some.client.library.url/mobile-sdk
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://gitlab.com/somesecretrepo' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.platform = :ios, '8.0'
    
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Resources/OPPWAMobile.framework'
  s.resource = 'Resources/*'
  s.resource_bundle = { 'OPPWAMobile' => 'Resources/*' }

  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice. Only x86_64 simulators are supported.
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'NO',
    'VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'x86_64',
    'SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/../../../ios/Classes/BridgingHeader.h'
  }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'

end
```

When I build the project and run it, the app crashes as soon as I instantiate one of the ViewControllers inside the the framework, telling me that it couldn't load the nib:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3EA9EB93-83AC-4CD5-BA87-748D318715FA/Runner.app> (loaded)' with name 'OPPWAMobile-Resources.bundle/OPPPaymentSchemeViewController''
```

I'm messing around with it for a few days, trying to figure this out but I'm running out of ideas how to fix this. I think the problem is how the nib file gets loaded from within the framework, because the bundle name is different or generally in some other context at that point. When I copy the bundle into the parent project's structure, it works perfectly fine - but that's not what I want.

How can I make this work properly?

Comment: How do you load the nib file? And where is it one, inside the framework, or on the app side?

Comment: That’s the thing - I don’t know it! Because it happens inside of the framework and it’s closed source :-(